# Is a set of matrix units a basis of $M_n(R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra

The reference for what follows is MacDonald's book "Linear algebra over commutative rings".

Following MacDonald, let us define a **set of matrix units** of $M_n(R)$ as a set of $n^2$ pairwise distinct matrices $F_{ij}$ such that:

(1) $\sum_i F_{ii}=I_n$

(2) $F_{ij}F_{kl}= \delta_{j,k} F_{il}$.

A classical example is the set of elementary matrices $E_{ij}$.

**Question 1.** Is a set of matrix units a basis of $M_n(R)$ ?

**What I know.**

(1) One may prove that the matrices $F_{ij}$ are linearly independent over $R$. In particular, this is true if $R$ is a field.

(2) More generally, Question 1 has a positive answer whenever every $R$-algebra automorphism of $M_n(R)$ is inner, because in this case, $Gl_n(R)$ acts transitively on sets of matrix units, cf. Th III.32 of Macdonald's book).

(3) Applying Exercise I.B.5 of MacDonald's book, one may show that any matrix $M$ may be written uniquely as $M=\sum_{i,j}t_{ij}F_{ij}$, where $t_{ij}\in T=\lbrace t\in M_n(R)\mid tF_{kl}=F_{kl}t \ \mbox{ for all } \ k,l\rbrace$.

Moreover, $T\simeq F_{11}M_n(R)F_{11}$.

So a related question is:

**Question 2.** Let $F_{ij}, 1\leq i,j\leq n$ be a set of matrix units.
Is is true that $T=\lbrace t\in M_n(R)\mid tF_{kl}=F_{kl}t \ \mbox{ for all } \ k,l\rbrace$ is isomorphic to $R$ ?